# Use Puppet Master as CA

Tags: certificate, puppet

I have a certificate that I use for https on a web server and I would like to use my puppet master to sign the certificate. I have the certificate generate but I do not know how to interact with the Puppet master. How can I sign an external certificate with the puppet master?

thanks in advance,

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: We already use puppet as a CA for managing Puppet nodes, since we are using it as a CA already we figured we would use it to sign a certificate that we need for a web server.

Comment: Those are different kinds of "signing" though right? The CA CERT for a website is just generated and verified and not really signed if I recall correctly (not really a sysadmin).